# Refresh VStack of enum cases in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an enum that represents school subjects called `Subject`. I have a LazyVStack displaying all the cases of this enum in my app.

```swift
LazyVStack(spacing: 16) {
  ForEach(Subject.allCases, id: \.self) { subject in
     SubjectCell(subject: subject)
  }
}
```

In each cell, a method gets called to update a progress value `onAppear`

```swift
.onAppear {
  progress = subject.getTotalProgress()
}
```

I have a settings sheet that gets displayed over this view of subjects with an option to reset all the progress values in a saved dictionary but when the sheet dismisses, I need a way of explicitly refreshing the list/vstack so that the onAppear method gets called for each subject again. Is this possible in SwiftUI?

Comment: It would be helpful to have an [mre] to experiment with, but my suspicion is that you can use `.id` to assign a new UUID to the stack when you want it to refresh.

Comment: `onAppear` is not a good way of doing stuff like this. `View`s appear at he discretion of SwiftUi and it is known to be unreliable